# When clicking the outer div, the inner div's event is also triggered using angular js ng-click

Tags: angularjs-ng-click

When clicking the outer div, the event of inner div is also triggered. Here I have used

```html
<pre> ng-click </pre> of the angular js.
<br><br>
```

eg.

```html
<div ng-click="outer">
   <div ng-click="inner">
   ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In html,

ng-click="outer($event)"

In JS,

$scope.outer = function(ev){

ev.stopPropagation();

}